# Load Fonts in Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to load fonts (dynamically) from the static resource,

```
addFont: function(name, link) {
        var css = '@font-face { font-family: ' + name + '; src: url("' + link + '");';
        console.log('addFont css: ', css);

        var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var style = document.createElement('style');

        style.type = 'text/css';
        if (style.styleSheet){
            style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }

        head.appendChild(style);
    }
```

The fonts are not loading, but if I hard code the same in the component they work fine. Am I missing something?

Edit: Fonts are loaded (from an AuraEnabled controller Method) on onInit which calls addFont.

Comment: When is the addFont event invoked?

Comment: Fonts are loaded (from an AuraEnabled controller Method) on onInit which calls addFont.

Answer (score 0):

In your case font files are already available as static resources. So you can create the font families in advance (inside CSS file) and only change the **fontFamily property** dynamically through JavaScript action. Here is a an example.

Component

```
<aura:component >
    <p id="cf">This is a custom font in Lightning Components</p>
    <select id="dropdown" onchange = "{!c.fontSelected}">
        <option value="">Select Font</option>
        <option value="Default Font">Default Font</option>
        <option value="Custom Font">Custom Font</option>        
    </select>    
</aura:component>
```

CSS File

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src: url(/resource/myfont/font/sansation_light.woff);
}
```

JS Controller

```
({
    fontSelected : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        if(dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].innerHTML == "Custom Font"){
            document.getElementById("cf").style.fontFamily = "myfont";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("cf").style.fontFamily = "Salesforce Sans";
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: But the fonts are loaded from the CustomSettings which refer to the StaticResource which means the Fonts are dynamic/end-user defined.